Differential equations analogue of fundamental theorem of symmetric functions
In Gian-Carlo Rota's article "Ten Lessons I Wish I Had Learned Before I Started Teaching Differential Equations", at the end of the third lesson he states a theorem:
"Every differential polynomial in the two solutions of a second order linear differential equation which is independent of the choice of a basis of solutions equals a polynomial in the Wronskian and in the coefficients of the differential equation."
Does anyone have a reference (with proof) for this theorem?
Thank you.

This is indeed what is stated, say here: https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Rota.pdf But what does that even mean? Are we considering $p(u,v)$ such that whatever basis $u,v$ of the solution space I come up with, $p(u,v)$ comes out the same? (Surely not.)

Yes, I am similarly confused, part of why I am asking.
